# Hotkey to toggle on/off window borders in Compiz

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz, ubuntu-mate

I want to create a hotkey combination to toggle on/off the window border of an individual window using Compiz in Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS.

Using CCSM I've mapped <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to toggle window negative, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to make a window fullscreen or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to make a window always on the top.

I'd like to known if there's a way to toggle on/off the decorations of a window by hitting a hotkey like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

I've searched in CCSM inside the Window Decorator section and I couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.